# Communication between 2 nRF24l01s and 2 Arduino unos

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, nrf24l01+

I am having a logical error that I can not figure out with the communication. I am communicating fine with the two boards such that I can send and receive data. Code to my [Transmitter and Receiver](http://pastebin.com/P6W9UTFN). Serial outputs [here](http://pastebin.com/KEENesNq). Using library from this site: (Sorry reputation too low to add another link)

*www.instructables.com/ORIG/FV6/0AAE/IBXM5ZIY/FV60AAEIBXM5ZIY.zip*

(**WARNING**: will download with out permission if you visit link above. Use below link if dont want to download)

*www.instructables.com/id/Wireless-Remote-Using-24-Ghz-NRF24L01-Simple-Tutor/?ALLSTEPS*

(Scroll down to step 4, library's are labeled as "library files.zip". Names inside the zip folder are "nRF24L01" and "RF24")

From the Serial outputs I do not understand why on my transmitter it says it sent the time in milliseconds, 5873, but on my receiver output it says it received 241. Also I do not understand how the millis() function on the receiver returned a lesser value than what the transmitter should have sent.

I have novice understanding of c++ and the nRF24L01 radio at best. Any information is appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint: `5873 = 22 x 256 + 241`. It seems you transmit (or receive, or print, I did not check your code) only one byte.

Comment: @jfpoilpret Good catch. This looks like the culpret: `radio.write(msg, 1);` - wite just one byte from the `msg` start address.

Comment: @Majenko Thank you for the feedback I changed the .write(msg, 1) to .write(msg, 2) but after a while it goes back to sending the wrong time i'm assuming the byte got larger. How would I write it to receive all bytes?

Comment: A long is 4 bytes.

Comment: Use sizeof() to get a type's lenght. Also check out github.com/TMRh20/RF24Network and RF24Mesh.